# Python 2.7 : socket.error error [Errno 111] - connection refused

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, tcp

I created a TCP server program (see [server.py](https://gist.github.com/bendacoder/de40acc77be44f08a120)) to access the terminal of another computer (see [client.py](https://gist.github.com/bendacoder/7418db15e15a6342f206)). When I use the client and server locally (only on my computer) everything is fine, however when the client is sending a request from a different computer, I receive this message on the client side :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 11, in <module>
    client.connect((serverIP, serverPort))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Note : the server is the computer which is being accessed by the client.

Comment: can you ping your server from your remote client?

Comment: No, I am unable to ping my server.

Comment: You'll need to figure that out first.  What ip?  Is a local intranet ip (e.g 10.10 or 192.168....)  you can do an ifconfig on your server to determine the correct IP to use in your client

Comment: Can you check if the firewall is blocking any external connections on the server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting the error "connection refused" in Python? (Sockets)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130786/why-am-i-getting-the-error-connection-refused-in-python-sockets)

Comment: Your code listing is not available anymore. Please copy it in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. I had to use the IP given to in when running ifconfig (`192.168.1.***`). I was binding to `localhost`, and thus I could not connect to the server remotely.

Comment: That wouldn't cause 'connection refused', unless the bind you refer to was at the server, not the client.

Answer (score 5):

'Connection refused' means there was nothing listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to.

It comes from the target system, which means that the connection request got there and the refusal came back, so it isn't a firewall issue.