# python-valve rcon minecraft 'ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused'

Tags: python, python-3.x, minecraft, source-engine

I am trying to connect to RCON on a minecraft server hosted on my own network using python-valve. My code is as follows(Keep in mind it is only accessible on my network, hence my connection to localhost):

```
import valve.rcon
def rconsendCMD():
    address = ("127.0.0.1", 25575)
    valve.rcon.execute(address,"jeff","time set night")
```

That code, according to the documentation, should work fine yet it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 90, in on_message
    rconsendCMD()
  File "bot.py", line 43, in rconsendCMD
    valve.rcon.execute(address,"jeff","time set night")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/valve/rcon.py", line 630, in execute
    with RCON(address, password) as rcon:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/valve/rcon.py", line 325, in __enter__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/valve/rcon.py", line 464, in wrapper
    return function(instance, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/valve/rcon.py", line 464, in wrapper
    return function(instance, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/valve/rcon.py", line 483, in connect
    self._socket.connect(self._address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The documentation for 'valve.rcon.execute()' can be found [here](http://python-valve.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rcon.html#valve.rcon.execute)

Comment: Have you tried running the script with sudo?

Comment: Just tried that, same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. I am hosting the server on a seperate machine from what I'm executing the python code on. I tried to send it to connect to localhost rather than my private address within my network. Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236998/python-2-7-socket-error-error-errno-111-connection-refused)