# TypeError: executor() takes no arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, networking

I have inherited functions define in class NetworkUtility in class client node by defining executor function.
Can you please tell me, why is it showing above error. I have no clue about it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
from NetworkUtility import NetworkUtility
#import json

HOST = ''    # get local machine name by socket.gethostname()

PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server,reserve a port for ur service reserve port



class ClientNode(object):      #if you don't want to inherit NetworkUtility


          def executor():

                 cn1 = NetworkUtility()
                 cn1.setupClientConnection(HOST, PORT)

                 cn1.sendMessage('Client 1: Hello')
                 print cn1.receiveMessage()
                 cn1.endConnection()

c = ClientNode()
c.executor()
```

Comment: If it is in a class, you are likely passing a 'self' for the class instance

Answer (score 1):

If `executor()` is a method of your `ClientNode` class, you need to use:

```
def executor(self):
```

When you run `c.executor`, `c` is the instance of the class being passed as the first argument to your method. `self` represents `c` in this way.

So the fact that you are providing one argument is right, but the fact that executor currently takes no arguments is in need of the above correction.

Comment: Can you format the code in the original question so we can see the indentation exactly as it is in your implementation?

Comment: when i put executor(self) then it shows            "socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused"

Comment: Well, that means that my answer fixed your issue. And now you have a new issue.

Comment: This is probably related to permissions, firewall, hosts file, etc. on the host you are trying to connect to... but I'd check the docs for the socket module to see what to do next. Or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130786/why-am-i-getting-the-error-connection-refused-in-python-sockets