# Client.py in socket connection not working

Tags: python, sockets

I have been trying to study the basics of socket programming in python. I have tried the code and the client connection doesnt seems to be working.

The code of server.py

```
import socket               # Import socket module
s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
print 'Got connection from', addr
c.send('Thank you for connecting')
c.close()
```

The code of client.py

```
import socket 
s = socket.socket()        
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12345                
s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```

When i run both client and server files i get the error     `s.connect((host, port)) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`.

When i run the server file the connection with the port 12345 is active but the client file is not connecting to it.I have tried modifying the code based on the suggestions online but still no luck.Any help to make this work is really appreciated..Thank you in advance.

P:S I am running this on my local machine

Comment: The answer is already available in :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16130819/15106950

Comment: i tried that but am still getting the error

Comment: You have an indentation error.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try Using another port as it seems to be an reserved port

Also
[image]

It seems an malware uses it So try disabling your antivirus as it may reset the connection

Comment: i have tried this before and i still get the error.

Comment: harish i have tired different port but still no use.I am running this on ubuntu machine